# Google Bigquery - Add a list of views to Share Dataset >> Autorized View using python scripting

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Im using python library to interact with google bigquery and create a group a new views, however, those view need to be added in a different share dataset as authorized views, but Im not able to find how to do using scripting due is a big amount. Somebody have an idea?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this is unfortunately,no. This can not be done directly as you describe in your question.

As per the official documentation "Currently, you cannot grant permissions on tables, views, or rows. You can set access controls at the dataset level, and you can restrict access to columns with [BigQuery Column-level security](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security-intro)" [Controlling access to datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#dataset-acl)
. Controlling access to views, requires you to grant a Cloud IAM role to an entity at the [dataset level or higher](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/view-access-controls)

There is however a possible workaround that would allow you achieve your goal.
It would be possible to share access to BigQuery views using project- level [IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) or dataset-level access controls. This is a very detailed walk through of how you could achieve this, it uses only two datasets. But the solution could be expanded for a larger number of datasets.

[The subtle art of sharing “views” in BigQuery](https://medium.com/@mbha_phoenix/the-subtle-art-of-sharing-views-in-bigquery-7fc553cb9e77)

Additionally, as you ask about using a Python script. There is no reason that the steps described could not be implemented using the Python [client library for Big Query.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries).

I hope this helps.